# how to separate a string into chunks based on the characters of the string

Tags: python, string, dictionary

So I have a really long string with words in it that are in between a "$" sign and a part of speech.  for example:
"$dog -v. an animal that is often owned as a pet"

What I want to do is pull out every word that follows a "$" and precedes a "v." and order them in a dictionary based on their part of speech.  In the example above, the output should be {"dog":"-v."}.  In this way, I'll have a dictionary full of words with their keys as "-v." to denote that they're verbs.

I think the best way to do this would be with string slicing and for loops, but the best I have is this:

```
my_dict = {}
for i in words:
    if i == "$":
        for j in words[i:]:
            if (j == "-") and (words[j:1] == "v") and (words[j:2] == "."):
                my_dict.append(words[i:j])
                break
```

but the above code has so many mistakes that I would rather people not point them out and just show me the correct way instead.  Thanks for  you help.

Comment: I don't understand. You first said the output should be something like `{"dog":"-v."}` (`-v` as value and the word as key) and then you said you'd end up with a `dict` where the keys would be `-v`?

Comment: Is it always going to be `-v` or could it be `-something else`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correct, you'll only select by "-v." which means a dictionary is not necessary. Also, a dictionary has to have unique keys, so you probably don't want to use this anyway - because animals could occur several times. A typical use of a dictionary would be the animal name as key and the amount of occurrences as value.
You are also trying to slice a character. When you are saying `for i in words` i will be character. Same goes for j.

This is an working example of your code with a list instead of a dictionary:

```
my_dict = []

for i in range(len(words)):
    if words[i]=="$":
        for j in range(len(words[i:])):
            if words[j] == "-" and words[j+1] == "v" and words[j+2] == ".":
                my_dict.append(words[i:j])
                break

print my_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

If `-v` will always be `-v`, you can use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) like this:

```
import re
s = "$dog -v. an animal that is often owned as a pet"
word = re.findall(r'\$(.* -v)', s)
d = {}
lst = word[0].split()
d[lst[0]] = lst[1]
print (d)
```

Output:

```
{'dog': '-v'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure about your expected output.

I am assuming that you will have other parts of speech tags like `-n` . Also, since you are unclear on the final dictionary, I have made two variants and you can choose the one which fits your requirements.

You may try this:

```
import re

sentence = '''
$dog -v. an animal that is often owned as a pet
$man -n. he is a man
$jump -v. he jumped blah blah
'''

animals = re.findall(r'\$(.*)(?=\.)', sentence)    #capture from $ to '.' 

posDict = {}         #dict stores POS tags as keys.. eg '-v':['dog','jump']
animalDict = {}      #dict stores animals as keys .. eg 'dog':['-v']

for item in animals:
    word, pos = item.split()

    if posDict.get(pos,'') == '' :
        posDict[pos] = []

    if animalDict.get(word,'') == '' :
        animalDict[word] = []

    posDict[pos].append(word)
    animalDict[word].append(pos)
```

**Output:**

So the posDict now holds POS tags ( verbs, nouns, etc ) as keys.

```
>>> posDict
{'-v': ['dog', 'jump'], '-n': ['man']}
```

Retrieve all verbs as below :

```
>>> posDict['-v']
['dog', 'jump']
```

If on the other hand you want animals and their associated tags :

```
>>> animalDict
{'man': ['-n'], 'dog': ['-v'], 'jump': ['-v']}
>>> animalDict['dog']
['-v']
```

Use which ever dictionary that suits your requirements. Don't use both!